# Help me identify this unknown SMD transistor

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount, modem, router

Could you help me identify this transistor?

I have searched every SMD code decoder and can't find the exact type of this transistor:

[image]

It apparently has CCE1X written on it, and has a SOT-23-6 package if I’m not mistaken.

It’s part of a router main board, blown because of using a wrong power adapter (the polarity was reversed).

Comment: It is probably not a transistor.  It is more likely a switch mode power supply integrated circuit.  The large black things marked "4R7" are inductors (coils.)

Comment: Is there any chance I could replace that?

Comment: The hint that it is a SMPS IC may not be enough to help you find a replacement - I took a quick look and couldn't find anything that matches.  It might be easier to find out what voltage those two regulators were supposed to produce and replace them with separate modules.  You'd remve the IC and probably other parts of the circuit, then wire in voltage regulator modules to the power input and output.

Comment: I haven’t checked what voltage that runs in the circuitry, since it just happened, but the external wall adapter output is 12 volts

Comment: Can’t find it but it’s probably a synchronous buck IC, considering the surrounding components.

Comment: Perhaps 5V and 3.3V, or 3.3V and 2.5V (or 2.0V, 1.8V, 1.5V...)

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly i read "CCEQ" on the marking (not sure).
[MCP3421A2T-E/CH](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/22003e.pdf) has a marking type "CCNN" with NN date/lot code in SOT-23-6 package. It is an ADC with I2C interface, is this related with the board functionnalities?

Picture from [ebay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/334776916312):
[image]